# Exiting a while loop in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

Here's the code I have question with:

```
isPet_list_elem = input("Pet?: ").lower()

# check if the input is either y or n
while isPet_list_elem != "y" or isPet_list_elem != "n":
    print("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.")
    isPet_list_elem = input("Pet?: ").lower()
```

I keep thinking that the loop would end when I enter either "y" or "n", but the loop continues to ask me for another input even after entering either y or n.

I've tried using other while loop to do the same, but the result was the same. What should I do to avoid this error?

Comment: Your boolean operator in the `while` clause should be `and` and not `or`.

Comment: Aha! Shouldn't I need `or` to return True for either situations?

Comment: If `isPet_list_elem = "n"` then `isPet_list_elem != "y"` is true, so the total expression is true. If `isPet_list_elem = "y"` then `isPet_list_elem != "n"` is true, so your total expression is true. So in any case your expression is true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do this and this will break the loop for `y` or `n`

```
while isPet_list_elem not in ('y','n'):
```

Comment: correct I just thought about that and came back here

Answer (score 2):

It's Demorgan's law.

You can say:

```
while isPet_list_elem != "y" and isPet_list_elem != "n"
```

or

```
while not (isPet_list_elem == "y" or isPet_list_elem == "n")
```

Comment: Yeah, ok. De Morgan's Law but the question had nothing to do with De Morgan's law. He was using the wrong logic in the condition for his `while` loop.

Comment: The question had everything to do with De Morgan's Law. That's why the original code didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong logic. When you enter `y` or `n` with your code, the condition at the beginning of the loop comes out as `True` so it continues to execute. Change it to an `and` statement and once `y` or `n` is entered, the condition will be `False`.

```
isPet_list_elem = input("Pet?: ").lower()

# check if the input is either y or n
while isPet_list_elem != "y" and isPet_list_elem != "n":
    print("Please enter either 'y' or 'n'.")
    isPet_list_elem = input("Pet?: ").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

If you enter "y", then `isPet_list_elem != "n"` is true; if you enter "n", then `isPet_list_elem != "y"` is true. And you use `or` in your code, so, if one expressin is true, the whole statement will be true.

you can use the following code instead:

```
while isPet_list_elem != "y" and isPet_list_elem != "n"
```

Answer (score 0):

Include the following inside while loop:

```
    if isPet_list_elem == "y" or isPet_list_elem == "n":
            break
```